# jQuery Mmenu: Want to have the navbar always fixed on top

Tags: jquery, navbar, fixed, sticky, mmenu

For my current project I'm using the jQuery Plugin Mmenu. Now, I would like to set the navbar fixed always on top. But it doesn't work, because the Mmenu even is already fixed because of fullscreen extension.

Comment: _But it doesn't work_  can you post what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to set the .mm-navbar positioned fixed with pure css. But when i scroll the Navigation, the navbar istn't fixed. I think it is the parent element, which is already set fixed/absolute - so i can't set the child as fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for it to get it done with css like:

```
#navBarId/.navBarClass{position:fixed !important;} /* <---add !important to have priority*/
```

and position `fixed` will set it fixed and it will always be on top whether you scroll your page or not.

Comment: !important doesn't fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Omg, it was very easy: I have only to set the right Plugin Configuration:

```
navbars : [{
    position : "top"
}]
```

Found on this demo page:
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/index.html?demo=menu-style-3